# Number "Terrain generator"

Tags: java, 2d, terrain

Recently I started working on a game I made a system that takes txt files with numbers and turns them into a visual map to play on. I made this code:

```
con = new Random();
p = new Random();
Height=12;
next = -1;
Width=16;
a = "";
ll = false;
gl = true;
All = "";
down = false;
File myObj = new File("res/test.txt");

myObj.createNewFile();
FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("res/test.txt");
Trim = All.replace(" ","");
while(Trim.length() < (Width*Height-6)) {
    if(gl == true) {
        All = All+" "+"0";
        System.out.println(All);
        System.out.println("d");
    }
    Trim = All.replace(" ","");


    Count +=1;

    if(down != true) {
        chosen = p.nextInt(30);

        Position = All.length();



        if(chosen == 14) {

            ll = true;




            System.out.println(ll);
            if(ll == true) {

                next = p.nextInt(4);
                System.out.println(next);
                //Cases
                if(next == 0) {
                    All = All+" "+"1";
                }
                if(next == 1) {
                    if(All.length() > 0) {
                        if(All.charAt(All.length()-1) != '1') { 
                            All.replace(All.charAt(All.length()-1),'1');
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(All.charAt(All.length()) != '1') { 
                            All.replace(All.charAt(All.length()),'1');
                            All.replace((char) All.lastIndexOf('0'),'1');
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(next == 2) {
                    down = true;
                    CPOSITION = Position + Width;


                } else { 
                    next = 1;

                }
                if(next == 3) {

                }
                if(next == 4){

                }
            }
        } else {
            if(down == true) {
                ll = false;
                gl = true;
            }
            if(All.length() == CPOSITION) {
                All = All+" "+"1";
                ll = true;
            }

        }
        if(Count >= Width) {
            Count =0;
            All = All + "" +"\n";
        }




        //End of Cases


    }

}   

System.out.println(Trim.length()+"-"+(Width*Height-6));
System.out.println(All);
myWriter.write(All);
myWriter.close();

}
}
```

The issue with that code is that instead of bringing me a lake (using the number 1)
it gives me this :

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I learned: when a 1 generates at a line it makes the line longer but it also seems like there is another issue I don't want to copy someones code I just want a explanation to how to fix it.

Comment: The input file is a txt file but the issue is that it generates the 0 and 1 you see What it should be a 16 x12 grid of 0 and 1 the 1 should be like a lake around the map

Comment: all of the info about the input is in the question